# How do I get Python to intelligently transform dynamic input into a fixed width output?

Tags: python, string, function, format, etl

.I'm trying to achieve something with Python where it can intelligently be able to transform an input and apply string format rules for a repeatable output, sort of a like a smart ETL function, if you will.  Case in point, I will be receiving numerical data from geographically disperse clients and that data needs to be transformed into a repeatable format so it can be consumed by our legacy financial engine.

For example, I might receive numerical data such as:

```
input = 123,456,789.4533
```

This input data needs to be reformatted to an output of 26 digits, depicted as (17)(9), where the first 17 digits are the values of the input value left of the decimal point, zero padded on the left and the 9 would be all the input values to the right of the decimal point, again, zero padded on the right.  So, if we were to transform it, it would look like:

```
output = 00000000123456789453300000
```

Now, there might be times where the input data would look like this:

```
123456789.4533
123.456.789,4533 (european currency)
```

What would be the best way to perform this in Python?

Comment: Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html)

Comment: what do you mean by "intelligently"?  does it have to somehow work this out by itself?  does it have to cope with new cases?  or does the question mean the same without that word?

Comment: @Joel: [Now you have two problems.](https://www.google.com/search?q="regular+expressions"+"now+you+have+two+problems")

Comment: @icktoofay Exactly.  I've been reading on regular expressions but I'm hoping for some additional insight to get my numb brain going.

Comment: Shouldn't the last example be `123.456.789,4533`? Or is that correct? (in that case, how do you know what's a decimal and what's just grouping digits?)

Comment: @icktoofay: Haha, yeah you're right. I've got regex on my mind since I currently working on a genetic algorithm to generate regexes. :)

Comment: @mgibsonbr You are absolutely correct, I will fix.

Comment: @andrewcooke I guess what I mean is that, maybe, this function can take in the raw input and maybe the format parameters and output the desired result.  Maybe 'efficient' is a better word to describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regular expressions

```
import re
inputs = [r'123,456,789.4533',r'123456789.4533',r'123,456,789,4533',r'123.456.789,4533']
for input in inputs:
    decimal = re.search(r'(?<=[.,])\d+$',input).group()
    integer = re.search(r'.*(?=[.,]\d+$)',input).group()
    checkdigit = lambda x : x.isdigit()
    integer = ''.join([character for character in integer if checkdigit(character)])
    print integer.rjust(17,'0') + decimal.ljust(9,'0')
```

**prints:**

00000000123456789453300000

00000000123456789453300000

00000000123456789453300000

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def transfer(input,euro=false):
...     part1, _, part2 = input.partition(',' if euro else '.')
...     nondigit = lambda x:x.isdigit()
...     part1=filter(nondigit, part1)
...     part2=filter(nondigit, part2)
...     return part1.rjust(17,'0') + part2.ljust(9,'0')
>>> transfer('123456789.4533')
'00000000123456789453300000'
>>> transfer('123.456.789,4533', true)
'00000000123456789453300000'
```

Comment: I guess, this would partition at the wrong place for non-US locale currency. The question has changed for Euro currency.

Comment: @Antony, yes, you're right. just noted it. I've modified the code accordingly

Comment: I appreciate your answer, as well as Anthony's.  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

If you're absolutely sure the decimal separator will be present, you can do it like this:

```
separator = re.match('.*(\D)\d*$', input).group(1)
integer_part, decimal_part = (re.sub('\D', '', x) for x in input.split(separator))
```

If you're not, you must know what the separator is beforehand, or your problem will be undecidable (what does `123,456` mean? `123456e0` in american notation or `123456e-3` in european one?)

Once you have the integer part and the decimal part, you can pad them the way you need to:

```
output = integer_part.zfill(17) + decimal_part.ljust(9, '0')
```

---

Explanation:

1. To find what the separator is, I used a regular expression to capture the last non-digit character in the input;
2. Splitting the string using that separator, you get the integer and decimal parts; removing any remaining non-digits on them, you get only digits.